# Replace Value in Excel Connection string

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string

Can anyone suggest a VBA procedure that would replace elements  of a Excel SQl Server OLEDB connection string?

I've tried with the code below but I think it's something to do with the data type of the `dbconnection` variable.

```
Sub ModifyConnection()
    Dim ComHostname As String
    ComHostname = Environ$("computername")
    Call MsgBox(ComHostname)
    Dim dbconnection As String
    dbconnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").OLEDBConnection.connection
    dbconnection = Replace(dbconnection, "___BTN_____\", ComHostname & "\")
    Set ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").OLEDBConnection.connection = dbconnection
 End Sub
```

The code is trying to replace instances of the computer hostname in the connection string with that of the current machine.

It throws error 424 - object required.

Comment: `dbconnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("...` is not a string, it would set ´dbconnection´ to a workbook object, but you would have to use `set dbconnection As Active.Workbook..` (without the `.connection` at the end). Do you want to change the name to the hostname of your current machine or do you want to create a new object?

Comment: I want to simply replace any instance of the computer hostname in the connection string with that of the current machine being used, so I'm not changing the computer hostname itself, I'm just updating the connection string to use the current one.

Comment: Try removing `Set` from the last line. `String` is not an object.

Comment: Now throws error subscript out of range referring to the line `dbconnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").OLEDBConnection.connection`

Comment: Go to `Data->Connections` and verify if connection's name is `ConnectionName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a simple case of wrong connection name. The operating code is as follows:

```
Sub ModifyConnection()
    Dim ComHostname As String
    ComHostname = Environ$("computername")
    Call MsgBox(ComHostname)
    Dim dbconnection As String
    dbconnection =     ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").OLEDBConnection.connection
    dbconnection = Replace(dbconnection, "???BTN?????\", ComHostname & "\")
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").OLEDBConnection.connection = dbconnection
End Sub
```